# rounding in python not working

Tags: python, rounding, polygons

I've been having trouble trying to round my answer for a problem where I find the area of a regular polygon and then square the perimeter. My final answer should be the area plus the perimeter(squared), rounded to 4 decimal places. My math seems to be correct, however, no matter what numbers I use for inputs, there are only zeros after the decimal. I have included a screen shot of my code and incorrect message from the checker that I use.

```
import math

def polysum(n, s):
    a = ((0.25 * n * s ** 2) / (math.tan(math.pi / 2)))
    p = ((n * s) ** 2)
    total = a + p
    return '%.4f' % round(total)

print polysum(8, 8)
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your math, `a` is always pretty close to 0, except for very large numbers, so you are just returning `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. Change `return '%.4f' % round(total)` to `return round(total,4)` or else you are returning a `str` round to the nearest integer. It looks like the expected output is a `float`.
2. The factor of `math.tan(math.pi / 2)` is incorrect. This should evaluate to `infinity` (if not for floating point approximations) and is clearly not what you want. It should be `math.tan(math.pi / 2 / n)`.

Comment: Thanks. I got rid of the 2 there altogether and it works now.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you're only getting zeroes after the decimal point, because you are using the `round()` function to chop off all digits after the decimal point. If that's not what you want, don't do it. Just do:

```
return "%.4f" % total
```

Or possibly:

```
return round(total, 4)
```

Comment: This is petty, but why use `%` formatting when `str.format` [is preferred](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)?

Comment: I did that and I get an answer of 244036.0, but the answer should be 263278.4681 with inputs (19, 26)

Comment: `%` is basically C-style formatting, so you don't need to look up how it works every time you want to use it like you do with `str.format()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
def polysum(n, s):
    a = (0.25 * n * s ** 2) / (math.tan(math.pi / n))
    p = ((n * s) ** 2)
    total = a + p
    ans = round(total, 4)
    return ans

print polysum(8,8)
print polysum(4, 89)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import *
def polysum(n, s):
    lst = [(0.25 * n * s **2) / tan(pi / n), ((n * s) ** 2)]
    return round(sum(lst), 4)
```

I have tried both the test cases. The output is matching.